# How to filter retention calculations in BigQuery by certain user events from Firebase

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, retention

I've made a query based on the one shared here: https://github.com/sagishporer/big-query-queries-for-firebase/wiki/Query:-Daily-retention
to calculate user retention in BigQuery with the data streamed from Firebase.

So far it has been working, but as the data sets get bigger, it is no longer able to run it due to the following error:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 129% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): sort operations used for analytic OVER() clauses: 100%

The query is the following:

```sql
    SELECT
      install_date,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 0 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_0,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 1 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_1,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 2 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_2,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 3 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_3,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 4 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_4,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 5 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_5,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 6 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_6,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 7 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_7,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 8 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_8,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 9 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_9,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 10 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_10,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 11 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_11,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 12 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_12,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 13 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_13,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 14 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_14,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 15 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_15,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 16 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_16,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 17 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_17,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 18 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_18,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 19 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_19,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 20 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_20,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 21 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_21,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 22 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_22,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 23 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_23,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 24 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_24,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 25 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_25,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 26 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_26,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 27 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_27,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 28 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_28,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 29 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_29,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN days_since_install = 30 THEN users
          ELSE 0 END) AS day_30
    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)) AS install_date,
        DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS event_realdate,
        DATE_DIFF(DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)), DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(user_first_touch_timestamp)), day) AS days_since_install,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
      FROM
        `dataset.events_2019*`
      WHERE
        event_name = 'user_engagement'
        AND user_pseudo_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
          user_pseudo_id
        FROM (
          SELECT
            MIN(global_session_id),
            user_pseudo_id,
            user_first_touch_timestamp,
            event_timestamp
          FROM (
            SELECT
              *,
              IF (previous_event='some_event'
                AND LAG(global_session_id,1)OVER (ORDER BY global_session_id, event_name)=global_session_id,
                LAG(global_session_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY global_session_id, event_name),
                NULL) AS match
            FROM (
              SELECT
                *,
                LAG(event_name,1) OVER (ORDER BY global_session_id, event_name) AS previous_event
              FROM (
                SELECT
                  global_session_id,
                  event_name,
                  user_first_touch_timestamp,
                  event_timestamp,
                  user_pseudo_id
                FROM (
                  SELECT
                    global_session_id,
                    event_name,
                    user_pseudo_id,
                    event_timestamp,
                    user_first_touch_timestamp,
                    IF (some_kill=1,
                      global_session_id,
                      NULL) AS session_some_kill,
                    IF (event_name='user_engagement',
                      global_session_id,
                      NULL) AS session
                  FROM (
                    SELECT
                      *,
                      CASE
                        WHEN event_params.key = 'Kills' AND event_params.value.int_value>0 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                      END AS some_kill,
                      SUM(is_new_session) OVER (ORDER BY user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name) AS global_session_id,
                      SUM(is_new_session) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS user_session_id
                    FROM (
                      SELECT
                        *,
                        CASE
                          WHEN event_timestamp - last_event >= (30 * 60 * 1000) OR last_event IS NULL THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                        END AS is_new_session
                      FROM (
                        SELECT
                          user_pseudo_id,
                          event_timestamp,
                          event_name,
                          event_params,
                          user_first_touch_timestamp,
                          LAG(event_timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS last_event
                        FROM (
                          SELECT 
                          user_pseudo_id,
                          event_timestamp,
                          event_name,
                          event_params,
                          user_first_touch_timestamp
                          FROM `dataset.events_2019*`,
                          UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params)
                        ) last 
                      ) agg
                    )
                  )
                WHERE
                  session_some_kill IS NOT NULL
                  OR session IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY
                  global_session_id,
                  event_name,
                  user_first_touch_timestamp,
                  event_timestamp,
                  user_pseudo_id
                ORDER BY
                  global_session_id ) ) )
          WHERE
            match IS NOT NULL
            AND event_timestamp-user_first_touch_timestamp<1.8e+9
          GROUP BY
            user_pseudo_id,
            user_first_touch_timestamp,
            event_timestamp))
      GROUP BY
        install_date,
        event_realdate,
        days_since_install )
    GROUP BY
      install_date
    HAVING
      day_0 > 0 /* Remove older dates - not enough data, you should also ignore the first record for partial data */
    ORDER BY
      install_date
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the Order by from your inner queries as order by can be an expansive opetation. Only leave it for the final step. Also Unnest can really increase the size of the records can you move your where closer to it to reduce record size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. In your `UNNEST` clause add a `WHERE` to reduce the size of the return records which impact performance, for example:

   ```
   SELECT 
     user_pseudo_id,
     event_timestamp,
     event_name,
     event_params,
     user_first_touch_timestamp
     FROM `analytics_185672896.events_2019*`,
     UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params)
   event_name = 'user_engagement
   ```
2. Remove `ORDER BY` in the inner SQL to avoid extra calculation where not needed since BQ will need to get all results and ORDER before moving to the next step in the execution plan, See this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UueWySREWvk) for more information

Comment: @maja can you please advise if this helped solved your problem

Comment: Thank you @maja for your feedback, Can you also vote up the answer which is also very important in SO for others to see

Answer (score 0):

We do this sort of thing in 2 passes.  First, we compute the days on which each user is active, then we do whatever calculations we need.

We use something like this for each user to store active days:

```
SELECT
    user_id as userId,
    BIT_OR(1 << GREATEST(0, (DIV(event_timestamp, (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000)) - DIV(user_first_touch_timestamp,(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000)) ))) as DX,
```

Active days is stored as a bitfield with up to 64 days per INT64 rather than individually calculating and storing each invividual day.
You can add more days as needed, 64 per INT64 by offsetting the shift.
The queries run and export very quickly.

This is UTC, you could convert to local time as needed.

We only need the GREATEST because we group by user_id and use account linking and when a user uninstalls, reinstalls and links, the user gets another first_touch_timestamp which is newer than older events.

Hope this helps,